# Python argparse required?

Tags: python, argparse

How can I make it a required argument only if I don't select another option, so when I select version it shouldn't require `-f`, but the rest of the time it should be required?

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="This script will check the uri's from XXX")

parser.add_argument(
    "-f", "--file", help="XXX export file to use", required=True)
parser.add_argument("-c", "--check", action="store_true",
                    help="Check the uri's")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--passwords", action="store_true",
                    help="Check the weak passwords")
parser.add_argument("-V", "--version", action="store_true",
                    help="Show version")
self.params = parser.parse_args(self.get_params())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, two things:

1. In the general case, this is done with [`add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) and adding the mutually exclusive arguments to that group (this isn't *exactly* what you want, since it won't *allow* you to pass both, but it's close enough).
2. In this specific case, you should be using [the `action='version'` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) for displaying the version, which exists specifically for this purpose, and leave `-f` plain `required=True` as you've already written it.